# ElasticSearch / OpenSearch term search with logical OR

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, opensearch

I have been scratching my head for a while looking at OpenSearch documentation and stackoverflow questions. How can I do something like this:

Select documents `WHERE studentId in [1234, 5678] OR applicationId in [2468, 1357]`.

As long as `studentId` exactly matches one of the supplied values, or `applicationId` exactly matches one of the supplied values, then that document should be included in the response.

When I want to search for multiple values for a single field and get an exact match the following works:

```
{
    "must":[
        {
            "terms": {
                "studentId":["1234", "5678"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This will find me exact matches on `studentId in [1234, 5678]`.

If I try to add the condition to also look for (logical or) `applicationId in [2468, 1357]` then the following will not work:

```
{
    "must":[
        {
            "terms": {
                "studentId":["1234", "5678"]
            }
        },
        {
            "terms": {
                "applicationId":["2468", "1357"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

because this will do a **logical and** on the two queries. I want **logical or**.

I cannot use `should` because this returns irrelevant results. The following does not work for me:

```
{
    "should":[
        {
            "terms": {
                "studentId":["1234", "5678"]
            }
        },
        {
            "terms": {
                "applicationId":["2468", "1357"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This seems to return all results, ranked by relevance. I find that the returned results do not actually match, despite the fact that this is a `terms` search.

Comment: add few sample documents with expected results and your mapping to provide working solution, but if I understood it correctly, my query should work

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with following query..

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "studentId":["1234", "5678"]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "applicationId":["2468", "1357"]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives me the exact same response as the last query in my question using "should".

Comment: In the end, using `minimum_should_match=1` worked.